# Django: Significance of 'RUN_MAIN' environment variable

Tags: thread-safety, django-1.5

While issuing management command `runserver`,  it runs the server with loader.  In source code of `Django1.5`  came across a piece of code
where before staring a server in new process/thread , it specifically set the value of `RUN_MAIN` to `'true'` in environment variable if its is not `'true'`

**django/utils/autoreload.py**

```
 new_environ = os.environ.copy()
 new_environ["RUN_MAIN"] = 'true'
 exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
```

In other piece of code it checks if that value value is being set ot not , if it is set then only it create a new process/thread.

```
 if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") == "true":
        thread.start_new_thread(main_func, args, kwargs)
```

by default in system(linux2) that value is not being set.

Queries:

1) what is the significance of that environment variable and how it is related to starting 
new process/thread.

2) if the `"RUN_MAIN"` is 'true' then code creates a thread, otherwise it creates a process. why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
1) indeed, the enviroment parameter helps to manage many processes.
2) the reason is autoreload (when you save a file).

You will understand the process here:

http://programmersought.com/article/49721374106/;jsessionid=766C1F404087AC1E369350A887C32A21

Answer (score 0):

i view django code ,then i google your question,bug not answer.

i talk about my ideas.

first，in`python_reloader` function, `RUN_MAIN`is not define,so run `restart_with_reloader` function.
in `restart_with_reloader`,create a child process, in child process `RUN_MAIN` is `True`.
now, parent process waiting `exit_code`.

child process in `python_reloader` start a new thread for server. Next,child process's main thread run `reloader_thread` function ,when code file change , run `sys.exit(3)`, child process quit, return exit code 3.

parent proces will run next loop,create other a child process, then reboot the server.
if `exit_code` not eq 3(example, you press 'ctrl-c'), parent proces in `restart_with_reloader` function return `exit_code`, code run end.

my english is terrible，i hope you can understand it.

```
def reloader_thread():
    while RUN_RELOADER:
        # waiting code change
        if code_changed():
            sys.exit(3) # force reload

def restart_with_reloader():
    while True:
        new_environ = os.environ.copy()
        new_environ["RUN_MAIN"] = 'true'
        # create a child process
        exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
        if exit_code != 3:
            # end
            return exit_code

def python_reloader(main_func, args, kwargs):
    if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") == "true":
        # new thread in child process
        thread.start_new_thread(main_func, args, kwargs)
        try:
            reloader_thread()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
            if exit_code < 0:
                os.kill(os.getpid(), -exit_code)
            else:
                sys.exit(exit_code)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```